# Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^8.0.0 in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

Finally after some years of reviewing questions posted by others it's time to write my first one!
Well, I installed Node.js and Cordova (state of the art) as per instructed in [this page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html), but at the beginning I failed to install either platform (iOS or Android).
After many attempts, I decided to give it a last try and run the *cordova platform add ios* command once again, and incredibly it worked!

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^5.0.0
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
        Path: platforms\ios
        Package: io.cordova.hellocordova
        Name: HelloCordova
iOS project created with cordova-ios@5.1.1
Plugin 'cordova-plugin-whitelist' found in config.xml... Migrating it to package.json
Discovered saved plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist". Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json
```

Then, I tried to run *cordova platform add android* as well, but it failed as usual:

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^8.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 4294963214 Error output:
npm WARN helloworld@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path d:\Dropbox\app\node_modules\.staging\android-versions-697b4c50
npm ERR! dest d:\Dropbox\app\node_modules\android-versions
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'd:\Dropbox\app\node_modules\.staging\android-versions-697b4c50' -> 'd:\Dropbox\app\node_modules\android-versions'
```

A complete log of the run is available if needed.

Do you have any clue please?

Needless to say I was running the command prompt as administrator, and the C:\Windows\System32 path is already present in the Environment Windows variable.

Thank you,
Fabio

Comment: ... I just found out (by complete chance) that adding the --force directive to the "platform add" command solved the issue!! Incredible that this was suggested nowhere...

Answer (score 0):

If i see it correctly, u are working in the Dropbox directory. Dropbox may lock files during its sync operation, which interferes with Cordova. Try moving the app to a folder outside of Dropbox.